# SMTP library: Dynamic email content

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I have this `sendMail()` method which uses SMTP to send out emails.

```
def sendMail(toaddrs, msg):

    # Set Credentials
    username = AUTO_EMAIL_USERNAME
    password = AUTO_EMAIL_PASSWORD

    print "Message received in the send mail message: " + msg

    # Sending the mail using google SMTP server
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    try:
        server.sendmail(username, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    except:
        server.sendmail(username, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()
```

It accepts a list of emails (toaddrs) and sends the message it receives (msg) to those emails. I call this method inside a `django` view.

Now what's happening here is, whenever the message to be sent is a dynamic content, something like a concatenated string, I get empty emails. Any idea why this is happening?

The print statement prints the proper concatenated string that the method receives but the emails are empty.